# Replace one image with another after clicking image and if click again then bring back the image in android

Tags: android

Replace one image with another after clicking image and if click again then bring back the previous image. 
I have written this code for my `RecycleView` but it is not working.

**Here is my code:**

```
private int i = 0;
        viewHolder.imageHeart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                i++;

                if (i / 2 == 0) {
                    viewHolder.imageHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);
                }
                if (i / 2 == 1) {
                    viewHolder.imageHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
                }
                Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: do like if (i/2 == 0){
                viewHolder.imageHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);
            }
            else{
                viewHolder.imageHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
            } and notifydatasetchange()

Comment: When you say "it's not working", exactly what is happening that you aren't expecting?

Comment: Please, add more details in the future and read how to format your questions.

Comment: I know it is solved but just in case. Your conditions are wrong, because when you click more than 3 times, i/2 is more than 1. I think you probably meant `if(i%2==0){} else {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this condition with simple `boolean`  like this :

```
private boolean clicked = false;
viewHolder.imageHeart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (clicked){
            viewHolder.imageHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);
            clicked = false;
        } else {
            viewHolder.imageHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
            clicked = true;
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try with else

```
private int i = 0;
viewHolder.imageHeart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            i++;

            if (i/2 == 0){
                v.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);
            } else {
                v.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```